# How to simulate closing of BaloonTip?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a NotifyIcon which shows Baloon Tips with some information. Is there a way to send some command to close this BaloonTip depending on my choice from within code (and not by using mouse)?
a) Click BaloonTip (normally by clicking anywhere within the TrayTip)
b) Close BaloonTip (normally by pressing X in TrayTip window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

To show BaloonTip:

```
NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(4, "Something", "Somnething2", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

To make BaloonTip dissapear right away one have to use

```
NotifyIcon.Visible = false;
NotifyIcon.Visible = true;
```